# Flash Air ANE Push Notification using New Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, push, air-native-extension, google-cloud-messaging

I try to register to new GCM with this ANE:
https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Push-Notification
iOS push is OK but Android version freeze with this trace message :
unrecognized event REGISTERING

### this is my xml descriptor :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.2">
    <id>com.arthesis.xxxxxxxx</id>
<filename>testPushNotification</filename>
<name>testPushNotification</name>
<versionNumber>1.0</versionNumber>
<initialWindow>
    <content>xxxxxxxx.swf</content>
    <autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
    <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <renderMode>auto</renderMode>
    <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
</initialWindow>
<icon>
    <image48x48>icones/icon-48.png</image48x48>
    <image72x72>icones/icon-72.png</image72x72>
</icon>
<iPhone>
    <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[<key>UIDeviceFamily</key><array><string>1</string><string>2</string></array>]]></InfoAdditions>
    <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
    <Entitlements><![CDATA[
            <key>get-task-allow</key>
            <false/>
            <key>aps-environment</key>
            <string>production</string>
            <key>application-identifier</key>
            <string>XXXXXXXXX.com.arthesis.xxxxxxxx</string>
            <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
            <array>
                <string>XXXXXXXXX.*</string>
            </array>
        ]]></Entitlements>
</iPhone>
<android>
    <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[<manifest android:installLocation="auto">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

        <!-- Only this application can receive the messages and registration result --> 
        <permission android:name="air.com.arthesis.xxxxxxxx.debug.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
        <uses-permission android:name="air.com.arthesis.xxxxxxxx.debug.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

        <!-- This app has permission to register and receive message -->
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

        <application>
            <!-- Only C2DM servers can send messages for the app. If permission is not set - any other app can generate it -->
            <receiver android:name="com.arthesis.xxxxxxxx.C2DMBroadcastReceiver"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">

                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                    <category android:name="air.com.arthesis.xxxxxxxx.debug" />
                </intent-filter>

                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                    <category android:name="air.com.arthesis.xxxxxxxx.debug" />
                </intent-filter>

            </receiver>
        </application>

        </manifest>]]></manifestAdditions>
</android>
<supportedLanguages>fr</supportedLanguages>
<versionLabel></versionLabel>
<extensions>
    <extensionID>com.freshplanet.AirPushNotification</extensionID>
</extensions>
```

App was build with Flash Pro CS6.

Someone help me ?

Answer (score 3):

They definitely need to update the extension for you. There are some subtle changes. We've just updated our distriqt native extension package [here](http://labs.distriqt.com/post/1214) if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I have it. Thierry

Answer (score 1):

This means they are still using the C2DM and android has stop accepting new C2DM registrations .

YOu need to wait untill the freshplanet build one solution for GCM.

I hope you understand.

Comment: but the documentation doesn't say.. :( see here https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Push-Notification#readme

Answer (score -1):

You can easily Integrate Push Notiffication in your Android Flash application using my [sample](https://github.com/VishnuGShephertz/App42-Push-Notification-on-Flash-Android) on Git hub
follow the steps written in ReadMe